# JSON understanding [object object] with jQuery passing values with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have an array of values and I have converted to JSON just so I can insert into an attribute (don't know any other way to do this):

```
<div data-categories="[[{"id":"4123","name":"Sushi Restaurant","pluralName":"Sushi Restaurants","shortName":"Sushi"}]]">
</div>
```

Thats what it becomes, however, there maybe more values instead of this simple JSON

```
[
  [
     {"id":"4123","name":"Sushi Restaurant","pluralName":"Sushi Restaurants","shortName":"Sushi"},
     {"id":"5555","name":"More","pluralName":"More","shortName":"More"}
  ]
]
```

Like so above.

Now I'm having trouble passing JSON with ajax to another file.

```
var cats = $('div').data('categories');
alert(cats); // this alerts object object
var categories = "cats="+cats;
$.ajax({ //json data for categories
    url: 'saving.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: categories
}).done(function(data){
    alert(data); //this does not get alerted
});
```

What I want to do with this data is to pass it into mysql, so I'd like to json_decode it eventually so I can use certain data

```
if(isset($_POST['cats'])){
// It doesnt' even pass through here?
}
```

Comment: The string `'[object Object]'` is just the value returned by `Object.toString()`. Moral of the story: don't use `alert()` for debugging. Use `console.log()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var cats = $('div').data('categories');
alert(cats); // this alerts object object

$.ajax({ //json data for categories
    url: 'saving.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        cats : cats
        },
    }).done(function(data){
    alert(data); //this does not get alerted
});
```

Comment: what if I have more than 1 variable `cats` and `cats2`. wahts the proper way of writing data? `data:{cats:cats,cats2:cats2}`? Also, what does this mean for my PHP? am I still passing `$_POST['cats']` or `$_POST['id']`, `$_POST['name']`, etc... the keys from the json?

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track you should post `data:{cats:cats,cats2:cats2}` then you can get the values using `$_POST['cats']` and `$_POST['cats2']` not `$_POST['id']`....

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
<div data-categories='[[{"id":"4123","name":"Sushi Restaurant","pluralName":"Sushi Restaurants","shortName":"Sushi"}]]'>
</div>
```

Also you cannot concatenate an object with a string, the value becomes:

```
"cats=[object Object]"
```

Since you are using POST method you should code:

```
data: {
    cats: cats
}
```

Comment: Its weird, I have in my PHP single quotes, but when I look into the html inspection, its double quotes

Answer (score 0):

If that isn't getting alerted then nothing is getting returned.  This may be because of a server error.  You may want to open your console on your browser and see if the AJAX call had any issues